# aiohttp posting list of jsons

Tags: python, aiohttp

I saw in somebody's code that they are posting a list of requests in one aiohttp post call, and expecting to receive list of responses back. I have tried that myself and it worked (if you are curious what I'm requesting, those are blocks of Ethereum, I'm talking to a live node):

```
def aiohttp_test():
    import aiohttp
    import asyncio

    async def post_test():
        req = list()
        for ind, i in enumerate(range(15544190, 15544192)):
            req.append({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": ind + 1, "method": "eth_getBlockByNumber", "params": [hex(i), False]})

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post('http://ubuntu18-1:8545', json=req) as resp:
                print(resp.status)
                print(await resp.text())

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(post_test())
```

and I actually got a list with two responses, however status is a single number 200. How is this possible? Documentation for aiohttp never mentions possibility of posting a list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code is making a single request here. A list is a valid json payload. Maybe the api you are interacting with supports multiple operations within one requests. If that's the case, you'll only ever receive one response.

Comment: hmm... Looks quite logical. I will experiment with it by sending array of requests using curl and report the result.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to pass a batch of requests to the server with one JSON-RPC request. In this case the JSON-RPC request is a JSON array containing request objects. The response will contain an array of response objects—one for each request object, which is not a notification request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making multiple requests. You are only making one request with a list of dicts as the json data being sent in that request. As you can see in the [`request` reference](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.request) *(which is what post uses under the hood)*:

> - **json** – Any json compatible python object (optional). json and data parameters could not be used at the same time.

You are getting one response back because of it being only one request. The status code is 200 because it was a succesful request.

Answer (score 0):

An example for you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python3.9+
import aiohttp
import anyio  # pip install anyio


def get_request_list() -> list[dict]:
    req: list[dict] = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(range(15544190, 15544192), 1):
        req.append(
            {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": idx,
                "method": "eth_getBlockByNumber",
                "params": [hex(i), False],
            }
        )
    return req


async def http_post(
    session: aiohttp.ClientSession, payload: dict, url="http://ubuntu18-1:8545"
) -> tuple[int, str]:
    async with session.post(url, json=payload) as resp:
        resp_text = await resp.text()
        return resp.status, resp_text


async def test_aiohttp() -> list[tuple[int, str]]:
    request_list = get_request_list()
    response_list: list[tuple[int, str]] = [(0, "")] * len(request_list)

    async def runner(coro, i):
        response_list[i] = await coro

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
            for idx, req in enumerate(request_list):
                coro = http_post(session, req)
                tg.start_soon(runner, coro, idx)
    return response_list


async def main():
    responses = await test_aiohttp()
    for status_code, resp_text in responses:
        print(f"{status_code = }")
        print(f"{resp_text[:200] = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    anyio.run(main)
```